# python queue task_done() issue

Tags: python, multithreading

I have problem with python multithreaded Queues. I have this script, where producer take elements from input queue, produces some elements and puts them to output queue, and consumer takes element from output queue and just prints them:

```
import threading
import Queue

class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, iq, oq):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.iq = iq
        self.oq = oq

    def produce(self, e):
        self.oq.put(e*2)
        self.oq.task_done()
        print "Producer %s produced %d and put it to output Queue"%(self.getName(), e*2)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            e = self.iq.get()
            self.iq.task_done()
            print "Get %d from input Queue"%(e)
            self.produce(e)


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, oq):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.oq = oq

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            e = self.oq.get()
            self.oq.task_done()
            print "Consumer get %d from output queue and consumed"%e

iq = Queue.Queue()
oq = Queue.Queue()

for i in xrange(2):
    iq.put((i+1)*10)

for i in xrange(2):
    t1 = Producer(iq, oq)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()

    t2 = Consumer(oq)
    t2.setDaemon(True)
    t2.start()

iq.join()
oq.join()
```

But, every time I run it, it works different(gives exception, or consumer does not do any job). I think the problem is in task_done() command, can anyone explain me where the bug is?

I have modified Consumer class:

```
class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, oq):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.oq = oq

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            e = self.oq.get()
            self.oq.task_done()
            print "Consumer get %d from output queue and consumed"%e
            page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip")
            print page
```

Now consumer after each task_done() command should connect to web site (it takes some time), but it does not, instead if execution time of code after task_done() is small, it runs but if it is long it does not run! Why? Can anyone explain me this issue? If I put everything before task_done() command then I will block queue from other threads which is stupid enough. Or is there anything I am missing about multithreading in python?

Comment: See the edit in my answer for your other problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Queue` [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue):

> Queue.task_done() Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete.
>   Used by queue consumer threads. For each get() used to fetch a task, a
>   subsequent call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing on
>   the task is complete.
>
> If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have
>   been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for every
>   item that had been put() into the queue)

For example in your code you do the following in your `Producer` class:

```
def produce(self, e):
    self.oq.put(e*2)
    self.oq.task_done()
    print "Producer %s produced %d and put it to output Queue"%(self.getName(), e*2)
```

You shouldn't do `self.oq.task_done()` here, since you haven't used `oq.get()`.

I am not sure this is the only problem though.

EDIT:

For your other problem, you're using `iq.join()` and `oq.join()` at the end, this leads your main thread to exit before the other threads print the retrieved pages, and since you're creating your threads as `Daemons`, your Python application exits without waiting for them to finish executing. (Remember that `Queue.join()` depends on `Queue.task_done()`)

Now you're saying "If I put everything before task_done() command then I will block queue from other threads". I can't see what you mean, this will only block your `Consumer` thread, but you can always create more `Consumer` threads which won't be blocked by each other.